# Query areas from DynamicMapService Layer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query, dynamic-layer

I have two dynamicMapServiceLayers. I have to query the area where three dropdowns are there. From a districts dropdown I have to select one district according to that mandals should be loaded to the Mandal dropdown, upon selecting mandal villages will come to villages dropdown. Then after selecting village, the geometry area of the village should zoom.

How to do retrieve that data from one of the layer?

Comment: Mercy, which version of the API are you using?

Comment: arcgis js api 3.13

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#querytask1).

1. Create a [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#querytask1), pointing at the URL of your service.
2. Create a [Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html) object with the details of your query (WHERE clause, etc)
3. Call `queryTask.execute(query)` passing your Query instance.

An example of this process is [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/query_nomap.html).